# GDB debugger switch platform (cortex-m3)

Tags: gdb, arm

I have previously installed GDB to debug C in eclipse, which is working perfectly. I want to do the same now with my cortex m-3, however I can't make a binary object using GDB because it is giving me an error.
I want to make a binary file the following way:

```
as -mcpu=cortex-m3  -mthumb   example1.s   -o example1.o
```

It does not recognize my cortex-m3 and it is giving me the following error:

```
 as: unrecognized option `-mcpu=cortex-m3'
```

When doing a version check with my GDB it says the following:

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
```

Is there a way to switch this to arm-none-eabi?

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question about gdb.  gdb is the debugger.  as is the assembler.

You want to build or get a cross-assembler.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it WAS a question about the GDB, because I did not really understand how it worked. I have fixed it now.
I have moved my assembly file to the folder containing my Atollic GDB debugger for ARM processors and did the same command. He interpreted the right MCPU, and the binary file has been made now.